# Can't understand why my python doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x

I do not understand why my program does not work, try everything and does not work, the program is to calculate the total amount to pay.

```
adultomayor = 2500
    adulto = 6000
    niños = 1500
    infantes = 0

    amayor int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de entradas de adulto mayor: "))
    aadulto int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de entradas de adulto: "))
    aniños int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de entradas de niños: "))
    ainfantes int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de entradas de infantes: "))

    total = amayor * adultomayor + aadulto * adulto + aniños * niños + ainfantes * infantes
    print("El valor a pagar es: " total)
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing some equals signs.

Comment: How could I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You Missed some equals,

```
adultomayor = 2500
adulto = 6000
niños = 1500
infantes = 0

amayor = input("Ingrese la cantidad de entradas de adulto mayor: ")
aadulto = input("Ingrese la cantidad de entradas de adulto: ")
aniños = input("Ingrese la cantidad de entradas de niños: ")
ainfantes = input("Ingrese la cantidad de entradas de infantes: ")

total = int(amayor) * adultomayor + int(aadulto) * adulto + int(aniños) * niños + int(ainfantes) * infantes
print("El valor a pagar es: " + str(total))
```